# Handling complex query in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple task with complex query, 50% is done i need help for the rest of it.

## Logic

1. I have landing pages where i choose category, then select
   specifications under that category and products related to this two
   filter will show in landing page. `this is done`
2. I also want have landing page when i select category without
   choosing any specification and it show all products related to that
   category regardless what specifications they have. `need help for this`

## Codes

this is my controller `i commented each part for better understanding`

```
public function landings($slug){
    $landing = Landing::where('slug', $slug)->Status('Active')->firstOrFail(); //find landing page

    //getting landing pages category id (in case one landing page have several category involved)
    $cat = DB::table('landing_categories')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)->get();
    foreach ($cat as $key) {
      $id[] = $key->category_id;
    }

    // i just add this to filter landing without specifications for if statement below **not sure about this yet**)
    $spac = DB::table('landing_specifications')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)->get();

    // this is where things happen (first $prod is responsible for landing with specifications and working fine, **else part** need fix to show landings without specifications.
    if($spac != null){
      //old
      $prod = DB::table('landing_specifications')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)
      ->join('product_subspecification', function ($keys) {
          $keys->on('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', 'landing_specifications.subspecification_id');
      })
      ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
      ->whereIn('products.category_id', $id)
      ->groupby('products.id')
      ->paginate(12);
    }else{
      //new
      $prod = DB::table('landing_categories')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)
      ->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'landing_categories.category_id')
      ->whereIn('products.category_id', $id)
      ->groupby('products.id')
      ->paginate(12);
    }


    return view('front.landing', compact('landing', 'prod'));
  }
```

Hope my commenting in code above be useful to you to avoiding misunderstandings.

> PS: I know I have 2 major issues here
>
> 1. My if statement isn't right
> 2. My else part need fix (but before fixing if() i am not able to see results of else part)

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I changed my if part to code below and now it is working perfectly

```
$spac = DB::table('landing_specifications')->where('landing_id', $landing->id)->first();

if($spac){
// rest of it...
```

hope it helps.

Comment: mark as correct please